Tibco EBX ~ Filter after Technical details
I need help with filtering in Tibco EBX rest API. I am trying to filter after "technicalDetails" information like lastUpdateDate or lastUpdateUser. As of the current Tibco EBX documentation, I can add the extra technical details using the includeTechnicals=true parameter to the Rest API call.
The model I am using looks something like this:
 "label": "Some label", "details": "<detailsURL>", "creationDate": "2020-08-07T17:10:06.834", "creationUser": "administrator", "lastUpdateDate": "2020-08-11T19:36:40.340", "lastUpdateUser": "administrator", "content": { myProperty='test', ... <other properties>
Based on Tibco's XPath Syntax documentation, I can filter my entity using the following syntax: filter=./myProperty='test'.
I have not, however, found a documented way to filter after the lastUpdateDate field.
Does someone know how to (if possible) achieve this?
I tried using different navigation patterns like:
../lastUpdateUser='<my string>' ../../lastUpdateUser='<my string>' ../../../lastUpdateUser='<my string>'
but the fields can not be found, returning a 400 Error:
{ "code": 400, "errors": [ { "message": "Unrecognized path: /lastUpdateUser." } ] }

you need to apply the complete xpath syntax, in this case: select?filter=osd:search(./lastUpdateUser, "Name")

Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, with this the complete xpath syntax like contains-case-insensitive or other, I still get the same error: 400 -> "Unrecognized path: ./lastUpdateUser."
